# Can I use hammer.js in react?

Tags: reactjs, hammer.js

Can i use hammer.js in react? this is javascript library. I searched react-hammerjs but it was deprecated. And i searched react-native-web and react-native-gesture-handler. react-native-web is use native components in react, and react-native-gesture-handler is mobile touch gesture lib in react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Hammer JS with ReactJS. React is a Javascript framework. All tools for javascript will work in React.

React is useful for managing the state of your app and using a components architecture.